# How to access objects inside array in php

Tags: php

I have a data from below in php.

```
       $data = [
           [0] =>[
                   {‘id’: 1, ’title’: test},
                 ],
                 [
                   {‘id’: 2, ’title’: sample},
                 ],
               ]
```

And now I want to print the value of all name. What I have done so far is but it’s not working. 
I only get a error  `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

```
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
           foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
               print_r($v->title);
           }
        }
```

What is wrong? please help. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that a `title` property doesn't exist? Although a `name` property does!... though that wouldn't give an `invalid argument supplied to foreach()` error; you'll get that if `$data` or `$value` isn't an array

Comment: I'm so sorry. I modified the code and changed the name to title.

Comment: Why are you using multiple foreach, one foreach() will work for you I guess

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying the following code snippet:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    print_r($value['title']);
}
```

Good luck